# Device Type and Screen resolution identification

Tags: html, device

Is there a way we can capture the Device Type and the Screen Resolution of the user who is using my Application.

I am using User Agent to Capture Browser and OS details but not sure how to get the Type of Device (like is it is Windows - if the device is Lumia etc) or the screen resolution of the user.

Comment: Do you want to store this information for analytical purposes, or do you want to use this information to display your content differently? CSS3 provides media queries and JavaScript can detect devices and resolutions too.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find the screen resolution by adding some javascript on my code...var orien='Portrait';
     if(Math.abs(window.orientation) - 90 == 0){
      console.log("Orientation = Landscape");
      orien='Landscape';
     }
     else
      console.log("Orientation = Portrait");

     if(orien=='Landscape'){
      console.log("Width = "+screen.availHeight);
      console.log("Height = "+screen.availWidth );
     }
     else{
      console.log("Width = "+screen.availWidth);
      console.log("Height = "+screen.availHeight );

     }

Comment: I need the device type for Analytical purposes only, Can you help with this ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can only suggest you take a look at services like Google Analytics for this stuff.